# read a csv file with specific pattern dynamically in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some CSV files with its extension which keeps changes all the time.

1. Active_Count_1618861363072
2. Deposit_1618861402104
3. Game_Type_Wise_Net_Sell_1618861383176
4. Total_Count_1618861351976

I want to read these files automatically

```
df1=pd.read_csv('Active_count_'.csv)
df2=pd.read_csv('Deposit_'.csv)
df3=pd.read_csv('Game_Type_Wise_Net_Sell_'.csv)
df4=pd.read_csv('Total_Count_'.csv)
```

I want this in such a way that I want to keep after the underscore dynamic and load the CSV files.
Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved outside Pandas using only standard Python functionality:

```
import glob

active_count_filename = glob.glob('Active_Count_*.csv')[0]
df1 = pd.read_csv(active_count_filename)
```

This assumes that there is exactly one `Active_count_*` file - if none exists, it will throw an error, if more than one exists, one will be chosen randomly.

Comment: cool. not to beg for the points but since you're new maybe worth mentioning: you can check my reply as the answer to your question, it'll also update the status of your question to closed

Comment: I am new to the platform and very new to python pandas, slowly getting used to it. Have done the needful as per your request